# POSTGRESQL ¿ Como hacer un update a una columna mediante otra columna de una tabla hecha por subqueries?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo estas dos tablas en postgresql. Préstamo y cliente

[image: tabla cliente]

[image: tabla prestami]

Lo que quiero es llenar la columna cli_promedio_ingresos con el promedio de pres_saldo de cada cliente. Para eso intente con la siguiente instrucción

```
update cliente 
set cli_promedio_ingresos = promedio 
from cliente as p 
join (
   select cli_id,round(avg(pres_saldo),2) as promedio 
   from prestamo 
   group by cli_id 
) as tab on p.cli_id = tab.cli_id;
```

Como se puede ver use subqueries y join para relacionar las tablas por el id. Sin embargo sale todo la tabla cli_promedio ingresos con un mismo valor 4000.
[image: resultado de la operacion]

Como puedo hacer para arreglar este inconveniente. gracias

Comment: Use https://dbfiddle.uk/ para crear un [mcve].